# Flex bind class property to mxml component

Tags: apache-flex, bind

Is is possible to bind class properties to mxml components ?
E.g.: I have a class `A.as` with a `String` property `nameValue`. What I want to achieve is always having the latest value of a `mx:Text` component in `nameValue`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just do this (assuming Flex 3 from your use of the mx namespace):

```
<MyComponent ns="whateverNSyourclassisin">
    <ns:A id="myInstanceOfA" />        
    <mx:Text id="myTextField" text="foo" />
    <mx:Binding source="myTextField.text" destination="myInstanceOfA.nameValue" />
</MyComponent>
```